# Convergence of definite integral and its analytic continuation

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, infinity, analytic-continuation

I have some very serious question (which truly isn't a joke) about convergence of definite integral in the form of $\int_{x}^{\infty}f (t)dt$, and its analytic continuation. To start, let's say that $f (t)$ is analytic.

**Question**: isn't it a sufficient condition to make that mystic analytic continuation (in most, if not all of cases), just by assuming that integral is convergent at infinity (even if that's not true)?

What I mean is, instead of $\int_{x}^{\infty}f (t)dt $ just write $-F (x)$

And thats realy works. Just try it for example on Abel-Plana formula. In case of Abel-Plana formula, if we assume that series of some function is convergent, its integral have to be convergent too. Just watch.
$$ 
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty}f (k) &= \lim\limits_{y \rightarrow \infty} \Bigg [\int_{x}^{y}f (t)dt+\frac {1}{2}f (x)+\frac {1}{2}f (y)\\
&\qquad\qquad+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f (x+it)-f (x-it)-f (y+it)+f (y-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt \Bigg].
\end{split}
$$
Now I assume that for $\lim\limits_{y \rightarrow \infty} $ integral $\int_{x}^{\infty}f (t)dt$ is convergent (so $f (\infty) $ too), independetly about fact if that's true.
$$ \sum_{k=x}^{\infty}f (k)=-F(x)+\frac {1}{2}f (x)+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f (x+it)-f (x-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt.
$$
I can't say if it always works, but if you try this on some divergent series (and yes, also on $\zeta(s) $, for  $ s \in \mathbb {C}$ except $s=1$) it works fine. There is only some problem when $x$ crosses singularity.

Comment: This is a strange way to ask "some very serious question".  The setup seems incomplete, and the goal is difficult to discern.  The notation  $\lim_{t\to x} \int f(t) \mathrm d t$ is not sensible since $t$ is *bound* by the integration.  Possibly you meant to introduce an antiderivative $F(t)$ for $f(t)$, but there seems little to say without a description of properties of that function.

Comment: I know, I did't assume any properties of f(t) and I will change notation to F (t). I just noticed that it realy works.  I will assume that function is smooth.